# I am getting this strange compilation error in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was doing the Coin change problem, I am trying to do it using Dynamic Programming. But I am getting this compilation which I don't quite understand. Someone told me that I have to assign the 'dp' array dynamically, but he was not sure why. PLease explain this concept .

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int solve(int *d, int size, int n , int ** dp){
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    if(n<0)
        return 0;
    if(size == 0)
        return 0;
    if(dp[n][size]>-1)
        return dp[n][size];
    
    int x = solve(d,size,n-d[0],dp);
    int y = solve(d+1, size - 1, n, dp );
    dp[n][size] = x+y;
    return x+y;
}

int countWaysToMakeChange(int denominations[], int numDenominations, int value){


int dp[value+1][numDenominations+1];
    memset(dp, -1, sizeof dp); 
    return solve(denominations, numDenominations, value, dp );
    

}
```

Error :

```
Compilation Failed
In file included from Runner.cpp:3:0:
Solution.h: In function 'int countWaysToMakeChange(int*, int, int)':
Solution.h:28:60: error: cannot convert 'int (*)[(numDenominations + 1)]' to 'int**' for argument '4' to 'int solve(int*, int, int, int**)'
     return solve(denominations, numDenominations, value, dp);
                                                            ^
```

Here is my Main file code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Solution.h"

int main(){

  int numDenominations;
  cin >> numDenominations;
  int* denominations = new int[numDenominations];
  for(int i = 0; i < numDenominations; i++){
    cin >> denominations[i];
  }
  int value;
  cin >> value;

  cout << countWaysToMakeChange(denominations, numDenominations, value);

}
```

Comment: in *countWaysToMakeChange* the var *dp* is a two dimentional array of `int`, not an array of pointers to int (e.g. `int**`). Note also in *solve* the form `dp[n][size]` probably does not do what you expect

Comment: out of that do not use variable length array (`int dp[value+1][numDenominations+1];`), and *d* content is not used in *solve* so the values you read to initialize *denominations* in *main* are not relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in the code.

First, in the function `int countWaysToMakeChange(int denominations[], int numDenominations, int value)`

```
int dp[value+1][numDenominations+1];
```

is illegal. Array bounds must be compile-time constants. Some compilers allow this sort of things **as an extension** (and it's legal in C), but it is not valid C++.

Second, the type of `dp` is "array of array of `int`". It is not a "pointer to pointer to `int`", and the compiler is complaining that it can't make that conversion when the code tries to pass `dp` as the fourth argument to `solve`.

Arrays are confusing. In most contexts, the name of an array decays into a pointer to its first element. That's why you can write code like this:

```
void f(int*);
void g() {
    int array[20];
    f(array);
}
```

Since `dp` is an array, its name decays into a pointer to its first element. But this is where it's easy to get lost: as I said earlier, the type of `dp` is "array of array of `int`"; when its name decays, the resulting type is "pointer to array of `int`".

If you want to pass `dp` to `solve`, `solve` has to take the same type: "pointer to array of `int`". But since you don't know the size of that array when you write `solve` you can't write that type in the argument list.

That's one reason why multi-dimensional arrays are often represented as one-dimensional arrays, with code to convert the two dimensions into one. The offset is `x * width + y`, or some minor variant on that. When you do that, your two-dimensional array becomes a one-dimensional array, and its name decays into a pointer to its first element, so you can pass it to a function that expects `int*`.